# How to choose best automation Tool combination with selenium

Tags: java, node.js, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

It might be opinion based question but I am really confused about choosing automation tools combination.

Till date I have been using Selenium webdriver,maven and Java to build automation frameworks. This seems totally working fine.

Now a days I feel that many automation engineers moving to use of `WebdriverJS` , `WebdriverIO`, `NodeJS` etc.

Someone told me that if we build automation framework using `WebdriverJS`/ `WebdriverIO`/`NodeJS`, Then execution will be faster than `Java`.

I know that I should choose tool based on my requirements but at the same time I feel that we can not use `WebdriverJS`/ `WebdriverIO`/`NodeJS` in some kind of website where all elements must be located by `xpath` as most of elements changing `class / id` dynamically.

So If anyone can just give me hint about which tools to choose for which kind of website then it would be really helpful. i.e For `AngularJS` website `Node.Js` is fine for automation with selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Selenium Official Webpage](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/), [Download Section](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/), you can see in the **Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings** section the following are listed :

1. *Java*
2. *C#*
3. *Ruby*
4. *Python*
5. *Javascript (Node)*

So from my personal take would be, these 5 variants which are the most widely used *Selenium Clients* while dealing with *Automation Framework* with *Selenium*

### Documentation

Leaving aside Selinium's GitHub ducumentation, its pretty clear majority of the documentation available on internet is on *Selenium (Java)*. It's because of *Java*'s world wide popularity as a *Language*. So learning becomes easier.
Even the frequency of *Selenium (Java) Client Releases* would support my native view.

But, personally I have found *Selinium's GitHub Documentation* for all the client bindings are perfect and precise.

### WebdriverIO

WebdriverIO is another variant of the Selenium Release. No doubt the *WebdriverIO* team have played it hard in building up the catch-up game with the *Selenium Client Releases*. But my take would be *WebdriverIO* is still evolving.

### Functional Perspective:

From a functional perspective my take will be either on *NodeJS* or *WebdriverJS*. Reason is simple I still feel the **Selenium-RC** way is still in practice when we inject **javascript** into the *Web Browser* once the browser loads completely and then use its `javascript` to drive the *Application Under Test* within the browser.

Comment: Should I prefer **nodejs** or **webdriver js** if website is built with asp.net or php and most of element locators are changing dynamically? as far as I know **node.js** look for properly **ng-model** always to find element.

Comment: Irrespective of the development bindings you can go for NodeJS or WebdriverJS. But as you mentioned **`ng-model`** so if the Application is built in **`AngularJS`** the best solution is **`Protractor/Jasmine`** combo.