# Browser Automation for Java-Applet based application using Fest or other java tools?

Tags: java, swing, selenium, applet, fest

I have a legacy web application which has UI controls developed using Java-Applet and trying to get rid of manual validation here. It runs on browser with JRE version 1.6 or higher ONLY in browser and we have no provision to access the JAVA Applet code. All we have is application URL and a valid user credentials to login. Selenium requires the UI components such as textbox, checkbox, radio buttons, submit buttons, links, texts etc, as html tags in order to interact with it. But here, the entire application is built with java-applet (some times swing controls) and Selenium cant control/access these UI components.

Assume if use Selenium (with java), we can login to application as login screens are plain html objects. However once application launches, we're not sure how to control the objects in it as they're designed using swings I believe. Came across FEST but its more of developer side tool which runs in development environment (kind of white box testing). So suggest someways how can I achieve by using any opensource tools like Selenium (HP UFT is out of equation considering the cost)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to choose best automation Tool combination with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303511/how-to-choose-best-automation-tool-combination-with-selenium/47304351#47304351)

Comment: @DebanjanB Sorry, can you please xplain how this question is duplicate? My question is actually how to tackle UI components developed using java-applets & swing components. But the other question tagged by you doesnt say anything about non-native UI controls, please enlighten me here.