# How to learn automation testing with minimum Programming Language knowledge?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

What should be the Roadmap to learn automation testing in selenium or any other tool after manual testing.

How can someone start learning automation testing with no special interest in coding?

Answer (score 0):

The shortest and simplest roadmap to learn [automation testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303511/how-to-choose-best-automation-tool-combination-with-selenium/47304351#47304351) using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) after *Manual Testing* can be:

- Choose the programming language of your choice which you would like to to use to write the tests.
- Visit the [Frequent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium?tab=Frequent) tab of [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) tag and visit the basic questions.
- Start writing the your initial programs.
- Start asking and answering to good questions on [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871)